# weird python "nested" for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I encounter the following for loops in another people's project, and I have never seen syntax like this before. It is sort of like a mutation of nested for loop, but not exactly. Anyway, how should I interpret this line of code? Or how can I unfold this loop?

```
for a in [np.transpose(np.array([list(B['v'][x]) + [0,1] for x in (face[0], face[1], face[2])]))  for face in B['shape']]:
    facets.extend([np.do(r) * scale for x in inflate(a)])
```

Comment: it is looping over the results of a list-comprehension.

Comment: Check out [an article on List Comprehensions](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python), this should help you understand this syntax.

Comment: Do you see `import numpy as np` in your project? If so - look at [numpy.array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html). Does it still looks weird?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contents of the `np.array` expression are:

```
[list(B['v'][x]) + [0,1] for x in (face[0], face[1], face[2])]
```

Referring to the above as `*`, the contents of the outer list which is being iterated over are:

```
[np.transpose(np.array(*)) for face in B['shape']]
```

Converting each list comprehension to a for-loop:

```
for face in B['shape']:
    y = [] # temporary variable
    for x in (face[0], face[1], face[2]):
        y.append(list(B['v'][x]) + [0, 1])

    # outer loop variable
    a = np.transpose(np.array(y)) 

    z = [] # temporary variable
    for x in inflate(a):
        z.append(np.do(r) * scale)
    facets.extend(z)
```

Comment: I suppose that OP  know nothing about `numpy`. So `np.array`, `np.transpose` means nothing

Comment: @AlexYu that is a plausible assumption, but then the question was about the for-loops, not `numpy`.

Comment: OK. Maybe there are not one but two or three questions

Comment: @AlexYu I agree that OP might also need guidance on `numpy`, but that should be addressed in a separate post.

Comment: Thank you guys. It is more about for loops actually. But any feedback is appreciated as I am new to python.